# Is it better programming practice to test in a superclass if it is a subclass and then complete actions or to have those seperate

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, inheritance

Specifically, I have two different PlayingCardViewControllers that have two different cardGames. Both SetCardGameViewController and PlayingCardGameViewController inherit from a general CardVC.

Is it better practice to test in the CardVC if the class is either of its subclasses and then complete the actions needed for each subclasses? This would mean that there would be less code, but it seems like it might be confusing. Should best practice depend on just how similar the methods are between the two classes? I was asking with reference specifically using `isKindOfClass:`

For example `if ([self isKindOfClass:[PlayingCardVC1 class]])`

Since I was asked for a more specific question here's my more specific question. Would it be better to put the following method in the subclass the way I've defined it and not implement it in the subclasses? Or would it be better practice to set the method in the superclass CardVC just to nil, and simply implement it separately in each of the subclasses?

```
-(BOOL)insertHighScore:(HighScore*)testedHighScore
{

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSMutableArray *cardHighScores;
// check if class is SetCardVC
if ([self isKindOfClass:[SetCardGameViewController class]]){
    if (![defaults objectForKey:@"setCardHighScores"]){ // if nil
        cardHighScores = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [defaults setObject:cardHighScores forKey:@"setCardHighScores"];
    }
    cardHighScores = [defaults objectForKey:@"setCardHighScores"];
}
// check if class is PlayingCardVC
else if([self isKindOfClass:[PlayingCardGameViewController class]]){
    // completely ignored this thing
    if (![defaults objectForKey:@"playingCardHighScores"]){ // if nil
        cardHighScores = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [defaults setObject:cardHighScores forKey:@"playingCardHighScores"];
    }
    NSLog(@"finding defaults count == %lu",(unsigned long)[(NSMutableArray *)[defaults objectForKey:@"playingCardHighScores"]count]);
    cardHighScores = [defaults objectForKey:@"playingCardHighScores"];
}
//... rest of the code
```

Comment: A superclass should know nothing about the subclasses that are derived from it. Perhaps if you gave an example where CardVC needs to know about the other classes, someone could give you specific advice.

Comment: Shouldn't this go in programmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: In theory the subclasses should override the superclass methods such that there would be no need to test.  But (with over 40 years programming experience) I don't take as hard a view as @user3386109 does with regard to embedding knowledge of subclasses in the superclass -- sometimes doing something like that produces simpler, more robust code than does doing it the "right" way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tommy's solution is a good one.  Here's an alternative solution.

Declare the method in the superclass to take the `key` as a parameter. Then call the superclass method from the subclasses with different `keys`. The superclass implementation would look like this

```
- (BOOL)insertHighScore:(HighScore *)testedHighScore forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSMutableArray *cardHighScores;

    if (![defaults objectForKey:key]){
        cardHighScores = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [defaults setObject:cardHighScores forKey:key];
    }
    cardHighScores = [defaults objectForKey:key];

    // ... rest of code
}
```

The subclass implementation would look like this

```
- (BOOL)insertHighScore:(HighScore *)testedHighScore
{
    return [super insertHighScore:testedHighScore forKey:@"setCardHighScores"];
}
```

In general, code specific to the subclass goes in the subclass implementation, code common to all subclasses goes into the superclass implementation, and you can pass some subclass-specific information to the superclass through parameters. In the example above, the superclass doesn't need to know anything about the subclasses. All it knows is that the subclasses will give it a key to look up in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: I'd describe this as not merely an alternative solution but probably as a better one, for the reason you explain: the superclass just provides some functionality; there's no implicit knowledge between supers and subs.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it better practice to test in the CardVC if the class is either of
>   its subclasses and then complete the actions needed for each
>   subclasses?

No. That's called procedural programming.

The runtime has conditionality built into it. When you do something like:

```
[instance description]
```

... figuring out exactly which implementation of `description` to call based on the type of `instance` is automatic. So if you do something thing:

```
if([self isKindOfClass:[A class]])
{
    ... path A ...
}

if([self isKindOfClass:[B class]])
{
    ... path B ...
}

if([self isKindOfClass:[C class]])
{
    ... path C ...
}

// etc
```

... what you're doing is reimplementing what's already built into the runtime, but less flexible, and in an uglier and more verbose way. What you should have written was:

```
[self doThing]
```

... and let the subclasses do their own thing if and only if they want to.

So the question boils down to: is it better practice to reimplement what already exists but less elegantly? No, no it isn't.

As to your specific question, you'd probably do this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSMutableArray *cardHighScores;
NSString *cardHighScoresKeyName = [self cardHighScoresKeyName];

if (![defaults objectForKey:cardHighScoresKeyName]){ // if nil
   cardHighScores = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   [defaults setObject:cardHighScores forKey:cardHighScoresKeyName];
}
cardHighScores = [defaults objectForKey:cardHighScoresKeyName];
```

Or even:

```
...
cardHighScores = [defaults objectForKey:cardHighScoresKeyName];
if (!cardHighScores){ // if nil
   cardHighScores = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   [defaults setObject:cardHighScores forKey:cardHighScoresKeyName];
}
```

Then implement `- (NSString *)cardHighScoresKeyName` on the subclasses.

(EDIT: though probably you want `[[defaults objectForKey:cardHighScoresKeyName] mutableCopy]`; if you put an array into the defaults then read it back you'll get a regular array — doesn't matter whether the original was mutable or not)